# I need to run some code only 40% of the times, how may i do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Rails] I need to run some code only 40% of the times, how may i do this?

i need to make some square items, and there can be a max of 5 per row, and a min of 1 per row. then i want to have a row with 2 boxes, 5boxe, 1 box and so on, random... the last box of the row, will have a clear:both class..

Comment: Perhaps you could go into just a little bit more detail on what you're trying to do.

Comment: A specific 40% or a random 40%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 for instance and check if it's less than or equal to 0.4.

Comment: Check should be "less than 0.4". The highest number returned, depending on the library, is usually 9.9.

Comment: It doesn't make any practical difference. Also without arguments, rand() return a number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive).

Comment: Does <0.4 or <=0.4 really matter? 40 or 41%?

Comment: Why are you guys arguing over using decimals? `rand(10) < 4` is a random 40%

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ensure that your task is run 4 out of 10 times then use this method:

```
some_task if run?

def run?()
 @i=(@i||0) + 1
 (@i-1)%10 < 4
end
```

**Caveat:**

You need to run the task at least 10 times to get the 40% distribution.
Distribution is not random